# Java Internet explorer 7 update

Tags: wine, java, ie

Unfortunately I have to use Internet explorer (7) through wine in ubuntu 12.04. The other browsers don't work with this website. But some java updates are required to open some pop up windows. there is a way to update java.

tks and cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running IE over Wine, have you tried [switching Firefox's user agent to IE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45753/accessing-ie-only-sites/45756#45756)? You can get the add-on at the following address:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/
```

There are also a couple of similar extensions for Chrome/Chromium:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/User-Agent%20Switcher
```

There is also an answer to a question that [gives you instructions to do it manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45753/accessing-ie-only-sites/45759#45759).

Comment: The requirement of IE7 is probably for OCX controls. However, IE7 is also a very old and insecure browser. I'm not sure what "this" web site is though.

Comment: I installed the addon in firefox and follow the guidelines in the manually instructions. Now I can enter the log in phase but then firefox tell me to install some 2 missing plugins. The search keeps going with no plugin found...

Comment: Did either of them work for your website? What plugins are requested? Otherwise, it might be the ActiveX controls mentioned by @dobey

Comment: Chrome have a lot of developers I didn't try all of them. In firefox the search for plugins continues..

Comment: In chrome I can't do the log in on "this" website. In Firefox I can enter but the search of missing plugins continues..

Comment: What plugins precisely?

Comment: It doesn’t say, only that 2 plugins are required, I press it to install and a window popup doing the search.. like for 15minutes so far..