# What plugin is needed to view video on this website?

Tags: multimedia, video-streaming

What plugin can help me to watch live video here
http://www.aasthatv.co.in/gpage1.html

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

**UPDATE**
Based on down voting and comments below:

There are a lot of devices which do not have modules ("drivers") for Linux but that does not mean that they can not be used on Linux.  E.G. USB modems http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/

There is a big community of people which provides work-arounds or hacks to make them work, so if a  webmaster does not know how to make things work on Linux that does not mean it can not be viewed on Linux there must be some way or work around because if on a Linux forum you say things do not work the way then why in the world I need to have Ubuntu on my system and if Linux guys can not figure it out how to make it work what is this forum for?

Comment: What message do you see? I see "We only support IE & FireFox in Windows, and Safari & FireFox in Mac." _Why did you not put this in your question? _ Do you not see something similar?

Comment: lack of knowledge does not mean things do not work if one does not know a work around there must be some work around and if it is not there why in the world I need to use IE in Ubuntu?

Comment: There are a lot of devices which do not have drivers for linux but that does not mean that they can not be used on Linux, there is a big community of people which tells work arounds hacks blah blah... to make them work, so if a video is not being provided by the webmaster that does not mean it can not be viewed on linux there must be some way or work around and that is the reason I asked....because if on a Linux forum you say things do not work the way then why in the world I need to have Ubuntu on my system?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45753/accessing-ie-only-sites

Comment: and probably this is the required plugin I need https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=tvu+player+for+ubuntu+12.04

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, this site requires a special plugin, which is only available for Windows and Mac.

You can download it with Ubuntu by using the “User Agent Switcher“-plugin for Firefox and use for instance this user agent configuration: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)`.

Anyway, this will only allow you to download a plugin for Windows, which will most likely not help you (you might try Wine, but I doubt any success).