# Is there any browser for Ubuntu that pretends to be Internet Explorer?

Tags: browser

I use Ubuntu 12.10. When I want to register for a service in some website, a messagebox appears saying "Please use Internet Explorer to use this item". The webdesigner assumes all users use Ms windows!
Is there any way this bypass this false assumption in Ubuntu?

I have Wine installed but I couldn't find it's explorer.

Comment: You can try out these solutions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45753/accessing-ie-only-sites.