# Installing Internet Explorer but broken letters

Tags: 12.04, wine, ie

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and am trying to install IE because I can take online lectures and they're only available on IE. I have VirtualBox but from then, I don't know what to do. I really need those lectures so I can study for my exams. Chromium nor Firefox don't work with the website. They only show squares and question marks.

When I installed IE, they said I need to install a plugin but I cannot click them. Plus, they don't show my language, only either squares or numbers.

Comment: Have you installed windows in VirtualBox?  If you have which version?  What plug-in it said to install?

Comment: Did you try with another "user agent" for your browser? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/45753/accessing-ie-only-sites

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Chrome / Chromium then try the following.

*IE Tab for Chrome is a browser extension that allows you to use Internet Explorer to display web pages in a tab. This is useful in many cases where a web page requires Internet Explorer features. Here are some of the many uses for IE Tab:
Display web pages that require ActiveX controls.
Test web pages with IE's rendering engine.
Use Windows Explorer view to browse the local file system, with full Explorer support for icons, right-click menus, etc.
Use Outlook Web Access.
Use IE-only Sharepoint features.*

[IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) for Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Squares or numbers can indicate missing language packs. Language packs can be installed through Windows Update under the optional updates. It could also indicate that character used isn't available in the font pack your are using. I would suggest editing your post to mention what version of IE you are using, and what version of Windows you are using as the fixes/problems will vary based on those factors.

ADDITIONAL SOURCES:

How to install a Windows 7 language pack:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813

What does it mean when my text is displayed as boxes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217228/what-does-it-mean-when-my-text-is-displayed-as-boxes

DejaVu Sans font:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/890949